# How come this isn't working Sync/Async issues with Meteor.methods

Tags: meteor

This is weird but when I call a external function from `Meteor.method` function it will always return undefined in the client I tried `Meteor.wrapAsync` but I think I'm doing something wrong. Here is my code:

```
var demoFunction = function () {
  //database operations
    var user = this.userId;
    if (!user)
      return;

    var count = Users.aggregate([
      { $group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}} }
    ]);

    if (count[0] && count[0].count)
      return count[0].count;
    return 0;
}

Meteor.methods({
 // NOT WORKING, How can I make this work?
 methodDemo: function () {
   var result = demoFunction ();
   return result;
 },
 // Works
 methodDemo2: function () {
  //database operations
    var user = this.userId;
    if (!user)
      return;

    var count = Users.aggregate([
      { $group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}} }
    ]);

    if (count[0] && count[0].count)
      return count[0].count;
    return 0;
 }
});
// Call from client
Meteor.call("methodDemo", function (err, res) { });
```

calling external functions doesn't work the same way if I put the code inside the meteor method why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Meteor.userId()` in your function instead of `this.userId`.  I think you are loosing the value of `this` when calling your function causing it to exit early.

Comment: omg, I was so frustrated I let it go unnoticed! Thanks it was it. I was thinking how come it's not the same thing there must be something I don't understand here lol :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared the function with a `var` it is scoped outside of `methodDemo()`.

You could declare the function globally by removing `var` or move the `demoFunction()` code into `methodDemo()`.

Comment: that could be a problem you're right but I'm actually having it on the global object already so it wasn't this case this time. Thanks anyway :)